# What are the key elements of a Service Oriented Architecture and how do they make an SOA effective?

Tags: web-services, soa

Service-oriented architecture (SOA) is a software architecture design pattern based on distinct pieces of software providing application functionality as services to other applications. 
Key elements of a Service Oriented Architecture are, application fronted, service, service repository and service bus.

Uses open standards to integrate software assets as services, Standardizes interactions of services, Services become building blocks that form business flows, Services can be reused by other applications, thus increased Reusability, Legacy leverage, Agility, Loose coupling 
and Interoperation.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Oh, Yeah, thanks Robby. I was wondering if my understanding for "elements" of SOA is correct or not, and specifically for each and every element, how could they make SOA effective ?